# adafruit 16 channel servo driver package

Tags: ros, driver, servo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a bit of a web search, I have come up dry on a ROS package for the Adafruit 16 Channel Servo Driver Board.  It wouldn't be difficult to make one, I just want to make sure no one has seen one before I reinvent the wheel.   Go to  [this link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/815) for the board itself. I'm thinking a simple subscription node that sends the necessary I2C commands to x40 from a RPi, and maybe a GUI joystick node that posts a topic with the 16 servo values.  If anyone has seen it, please let me know.  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224490/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-package/) by [LukeH](https://answers.ros.org/users/25639/lukeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i use the https://www.adafruit.com/products/2327  16-Channel PWM / Servo HAT for Raspberry Pi  which is perhaps the same chip.

i got a https://github.com/flobotics/flobotics_servo_pwm_pi  listener node, to which you can send int16 values for every servo, feel free to use it , or modify it

---

Originally posted by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) with karma: 406 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LukeH](https://answers.ros.org/users/25639/lukeh/) on 2016-01-20**:
Perfect thanks!